# database update using switchery switch using ajax in codeigniter

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter, checkbox

I am developing an attendance management codeigniter app and I am using switchery switch plugin to update attendance status. The process will be:

1. System display the list of student with attendance status in checkbox with switchery plugin.
2. Using check or uncheck the checkbox with switchery plugin, if the student is present or absent or simply user change the status.
3. System sends the form using AJAX, if the student present 1 or absent 0, with student ID and attendance date.
4. And simply system will change the attendance status of student.
5. NOTE* THE VALUE OF **$date** **$month** **$year** **$program_id** **$batch_id** and **$section_id** is loaded before in controller function parameter.

And this my app's preview. I need to this form working using AJAX.

[image: preview of attendance app with switchery plugin]

And this is my code for the view:

```html
<!-- student attendence status update form -->
<form method="post" action="<?php echo base_url(); ?>index.php?admin/student_attendance">
  <!-- start datatable -->
  <table class="table table-hover dataTable table-striped width-full" id="departmentTableTools">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th class="text-center"><?php echo get_phrase('rool'); ?></th>
        <th class="text-center"><?php echo get_phrase('name'); ?></th>
        <th class="text-center"><?php echo get_phrase('status'); ?></th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <?php
foreach($students as $row):?>
      <tr>
        <td class="text-center"><?php echo $row['roll_no'];?></td>
        <td class="text-center"><?php echo $row['name'];?></td>
        <td class="text-center">
          <input type="checkbox" value="1" name="status_<?php echo $row['student_id'];?>" data-plugin="switchery" <?php if($status == 1) echo 'checked'; ?>/>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <?php endforeach;?>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  <input type="hidden" name="date" value="<?php echo $full_date;?>" />
</form>
<!-- end the attendance status update form -->
```

And this my controller code:

```html
if($_POST) // if the update request is send
{
foreach ($students as $row)
{
$this->crud_model->update_student_attendance($students['student_id'], $this->input->post('status_' . $row['student_id']), $this->input->post('date'));
}
$this->session->set_flashdata('flash_message' , get_phrase('data_updated'));
redirect(base_url() . 'index.php?admin/student_attendance/'.$date.'/'.$month.'/'.$year.'/'.$program_id.'/'.$batch_id , 'refresh');
}
```

And this is my model code to update and db values:

```html
function update_student_attendance($student_id, $attendance_status, $full_date){
$this->db->where('student_id' , $student_id);
$this->db->where('date' , $full_date);
$this->db->update('attendance' , array('status' => $attendance_status));
}
```

Comment: Do you mind formatting your code a little bit? And didn't you say you were using CodeIgniter? Could you separate Views and PHP from same file?

Comment: Thank You @Nishchal .. i am going to format it  and separate all the queries from to model. But do you have any suggestion regarding to my problem.

Comment: I've no idea what's happening in the code, I didn't even read it because the code was not formatted, at least have some indentation, after that I'll help you out with this as I've recently done a Attendance Management System and I am now including online exams and other features. :)

Comment: Hello @Nischal... please review my code is the code follows the standard or not?? i am new to MVC and need your help to dynamically updating attendance status using ajax. :)

Comment: @SumanDahal can you clear what you expect as answer and what you need

Comment: @Abdulla  I have the student attendance form where all the students are loaded in tabular view, for reference you can view the sample app screenshot on the top. i need to update the database just 0 for absent and 1 for present while user checked and unchecked the checkbox without refreshing the page or using ajax. 

did you get what i mean ... sorry for my poor grammar

Comment: `$status_studentId ` getting any result??

Comment: yes it will display $status_1 for student id 1 ... i can make this form working using dropdown with present and absent values, and with php send values to controller .but since i have list of student in it and i want it to be very simple as possible,  while user check or uncheck the box the ajax request sends data to controller and update my db without reloading the page.

Comment: @Abdulla we have load shedding problem in here... so i will unable to post any comment after 3 min and i will clarify and keep you update tomorrow as well. Hope to get your great help on this issue.