# how to avoid from loading unnecessary javascript and css in page on codeigniter to improve the load time

Tags: javascript, css, codeigniter

Generally all the css and javascript is loaded in the top and bottom respectively. But on some pages there is no need of load all the javascript and css files. So, how do i prevent to load the unnecessary files from the selected page.

Comment: From your codeigniter controller send and array of names of js files and css and in view just load them so only required items will be loaded

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two thing to do.

1. Divide the header CSS and JS  to separate files.
2. Ignore it.

---

**Method 01**

if your home page load slider and all. So create header  only for home with `header_home.php`. and other pages just use css and JS. so remove slider JS and CSS and create another one with `header_inner.php`

**Method 02**

Just leave it has it is. Cz it will not affect to your site performance. Its works once is called out only

Comment: vote up for get high rep

Comment: Thank You @abdulla for your precious feedback. I will divide the css and javascript :) and also if you have time please help me to solve another question as well because it almost 3 days i have posted another question related to update database values using ajax with checkbox. the question link is : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34545927/database-update-using-switchery-switch-using-ajax-in-codeigniter

Answer (score 1):

Use this code for load js and css on particular page.

```
<?php $is_checkout = $this->router->fetch_class() === 'checkout' ? true : false;
if($is_checkout){?>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>js/front_side/checkout-payment.js"></script>
<?php } ?>
```

Use controller name ex: home,checkout.

Comment: Thank you for your precious help @Shraddha ...

Answer (score 0):

you can simply create different views like header_links and footer_links view for different pages and load them to respective pages where they are needed.

```
   <?php $this->load->view('home_links'); ?>  //for home page

 <?php $this->load->view('contact_links'); ?>  // for contact page
```